# Get rows with second-most-recent timestamp by category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (called `formstatus`) with 4 columns: `id`, `form`, `status`, and `timestamp`, with `id` as the primary key and `form` and `status` unique together. I would like to get the set of rows (the `status` in particular) with the second-most-recent timestamp per `form`. I tried

```
SELECT form, status FROM (
  SELECT form, status, timestamp
  FROM formstatus
  WHERE timestamp < max(timestamp)
  GROUP BY form) as a
WHERE timestamp = max(timestamp)
GROUP BY form
```

but it didn't work because apparently aggregates are not allowed in where clauses. So, is there a query that *will* return the information I am looking for?

Comment: I don't think you can have `MAX()` function in `WHERE`. Try using `HAVING`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.*, COUNT(*) pos
FROM formstatus t1
  LEFT JOIN formstatus t2
    ON t2.form = t1.form AND t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp
GROUP BY
  t1.form, t1.timestamp
HAVING
  pos = 2;
```

Comment: OK, this seems to work. Do you think you could give a little explanation of why it works? I've never seen `COUNT(*)` used that way before.

Comment: Remove HAVING clause from the query and you will see ordinary rank-query.

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution, since it's a bit more explicit than the LIMIT 1,1 method.  The only downside I see is that the resulting query must include the count, which is hardly bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated because you cannot use aggregates in a `WHERE` clause.  Try moving your condition to a `HAVING` clause.

```
GROUP BY form
HAVING timestamp < max(timestamp)
```